# How to compare one set of data to another and choose the smallest degree value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a code for determining some value by two methods. My data is in dataframe and I choose two time intervals and by changing the times within these two time intervals and find the smallest degree value.
My data is in following form: It's just an example.

```
df:
epoch                r1         r2      r3
2020-07-07T08:17    -6.366163  11.8    -1.2
2020-07-07T08:18    -5.163     10.38   -2.5
2020-07-07T08:19    -4.3        9.4     5.2
...........
2020-07-07T14:00    1 0.25      22.2    1.5
```

[Here is my data https://www.dropbox.com/s/39yre6y85luu3tj/example.csv?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/39yre6y85luu3tj/example.csv?dl=0)
I divide the data set into two selected regions like from 2020-07-07 09:10 to 10:00 as the one selected region, and
2020-07-07 11:10 to 13:00 as the other selected region.
For example:

```
df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df.epoch, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df['time'] = df['epoch'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')

first_datetime = '2020-07-07 09:10'  
second_datetime = '2020-07-07 10:00'
third_datetime = '2020-07-07 11:10'  
fourth_datetime = '2020-07-07 13:00'
first = datetime.strptime(first_datetime , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime('%H:%M')        
second = datetime.strptime(second_datetime , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime('%H:%M')        
third = datetime.strptime(third_datetime , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime('%H:%M')        
fourth = datetime.strptime(fourth_datetime , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").strftime('%H:%M')
```

And then I do two different procedures with the divided regions and df_1 indicates the first selected region and df_2 indicates the second selected region:
First method is just some matrix stuff

```
df_1 = df.loc[(df["time"] >= first) & (df["time"] <= second)]
df_2 = df.loc[(df["time"] >= third) & (df["time"] <= fourth)]
df_add = df_1.append(df_2, ignore_index = True)
rx, ry, rz = (df_add['r1'], df_add['r2'], df_add['r3'])
data = np.array([rx,ry,rz])
covMatrix = np.cov(data,bias=True)
eigval_mva, eigvec_mva = np.linalg.eig(covMatrix)
eigval_mva = eigval_mva.real
mincol = list(eigval_mva).index(min(eigval_mva))
eigenvect = eigvec_mva[:,mincol]
print(eigenvect)
```

second one is also some algorithmic stuff

```
df_u = df_1
df_d = df_2

rx_1 = df_1['r1'].mean()
ry_1 = df_1['r2'].mean()
rz_1 = df_1['r3'].mean()
rx_2 = df_2['r1'].mean()
ry_2 = df_2['r2'].mean()
rz_2 = df_2['r3'].mean()
r_1 = (rx_1, ry_1, rz_1)
r_2 = (rx_2, ry_2, rz_2)
r_1_vec = np.array(r_1)
r_2_vec = np.array(r_2)
def cross(a,b):
    return np.cross(a,b)
def norm(v):
    return v/(np.linalg.norm(v))
v = cross(np.subtract(r_1_vec, r_2_vec), cross(r_1_vec, r_2_vec))
nor = norm(v)

print(nor)
```

And finally, I compare the two methods by their angle

```
import math
def angle(v1,v2):
    unit_vector_1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)
    unit_vector_2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)
    dot_product = np.dot(unit_vector_1, unit_vector_2)
    return np.arccos(dot_product)
a = angle(eigenvect,nor)
deg = np.rad2deg(a)
print(deg)
```

So, my question is how to run this process many times by varying times within selected regions and then choosing the smallest degree it gives?
What I mean is for example I restrict the first chosen region to be from maybe 09:00 o'clock to 11:00 o'clock and the second region to be 11:00 to 12:00 o'clock and changing the intervals in the restricted time of the two regions and finding the smallest possible degree combinations and printing the time interval for two regions which give the smallest degree.
In other words I restrict df_1 and df_2 in some intervals and varying them within that intervals to find the smallest degree value
How to implement this.

Edit: As requested my explanation.
As I stated before, the whole purpose of procedure is searching for two intervals that I can use in the places of df_1 and df_2. Somehow setting the intervals, I can reach two interval sets in which the methods agree the most by their least degree difference.
Best set of intervals are the method results are in degree difference < 1 degree and the bad ones are everything above 10 degrees are the bad ones.
I can find such interval in which the methods agree the most, but I could have been missing some intervals, which could be far more accurate. So, in order to find the true value or the ones who are closer to the true value, I need to check every possible combinations within constraints that I set for two intervals each.

Comment: Sorry if it is too vague. I just want to find the best possible two intervals that gives me the smallest degree possible by the codes above. I'm trying to find the interval that the two codes agree by the smallest degree possible from data.

Comment: I uploaded the data. 
The reason for looking at eigenvalues is I'm picking the eigenvector which corresponds to  the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: All in all, if two methods agree by their smallest angles because two methods provide me two sets of vectors and by finding the smallest degree value indicates the best two selected regions. 
I can do it by hand by selecting from which (t0..t1) and (t2...t3) intervals, but I want to do it by looping via (t0 running to  t1) and (t2 running to t3)

Comment: What is the geometric interpretation of the operations you are doing? The "best two selected regions": with regard to what objective? You are selecting the eigenvector corresponding to the _smallest_ eigenvalue, i.e., the direction of smallest variance for your 3D cloud of points (made by combining the two samples). In the case of a spherical cloud (or any cloud with spherical inertia, i.e. where all eigenvalues are close to each other), please note that this direction is essentially random (as well as the other eigenvectors): it can be affected by a single extra point.

Comment: Maybe I'm using wrong words here. Not regions, but best two intervals regard to the smallest angle they give. The reason for the smallest angle is just by two methods I'm trying to find the similar two sets of vectors possible from the two methods. Let's say I set two intervals maximum range to be 09:00 to 11:00 for the first interval and 12:00 to 13:30 for the second interval.

Comment: What I want to do is looping from 09:00 to 11:00 o'clock, which is 2 hours by adding 1 minutes each like 09:01, 09:02 to 11:00, which means each time the first time interval increase by 1 minute like the first interval becomes 1 minute second 2 minute and so on but since I'm trying find an interval, the loop also must go to 11:00 from 09:00 by decreasing order as well, in which case first its time interval is 2 hours then 1:59 minutes, then 1:58 minute till it becomes 10:59 to 11:00. This is all for the first interval that I, for example, set for the first interval

Comment: while the second interval that I set from 12:00 to 13:30 also do the exact same looping. The first interval indicates df_1 and the second interval indicates df_2.

Comment: For the eigenvalue, I'd say that the ratio of the smallest eigenvalue to the middle eigenvalue should or favorable to be less than 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here are some pointers towards a mechanical answer to the question. It feels unsatisfying because I still don't fully understand what the higher objective function is that we want to optimize.

My understanding so far is that a `df` is given, containing a time series of points in 3 dimensions. The OP wants to find two contiguous and distinct subsets of `df` (defined by two non-overlapping intervals of time), such that some measure of dissimilarity between the two subsets is minimized. These two subsets are two clouds of points. Two metrics are used:

1. the direction of minimum variance of the combined clouds, obtained by PCA (eigensystem of the covariance matrix of all points);
2. the direction orthogonal to the vector difference between the clouds' barycenters, and coplanar with `(origin, mean_1, mean_2)`. Since the problem is 3-dimensional, the OP uses cross-products to calculate this.

The measure to minimize is the angle between these two metrics. No intuitive explanation as to why that is desirable has been provided at the time of this writing. In addition to the lack of intuition, there are caveats to both metrics (see the Discussion section below).

In any case, the following is a brute-force answer. It will take forever on any reasonable size dataset. It examines every pair of intervals satisfying the OP's constraints and selects the pair of intervals for which the measure is minimum. The constraints are that the two intervals are each drawn from bigger, non-verlapping ones that are given.

#### Some code cleanup

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def select(df, t0, t1, t2, t3):
    df1 = df.truncate(before=t0, after=t1)
    df2 = df.truncate(before=t2, after=t3)
    return df1, df2

def eigen(df1, df2):
    data = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).values.T
    covMatrix = np.cov(data, bias=True)
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(covMatrix)
    return w.real, v

def norm(v):
    return v / np.linalg.norm(v)

def crossdir(df1, df2):
    r1 = df1.mean().values
    r2 = df2.mean().values
    v = np.cross(r1 - r2, np.cross(r1, r2))
    return norm(v)

def angle(v1, v2):
    dp = np.dot(norm(v1), norm(v2))
    return np.arccos(dp)

def measure(df1, df2, eig_mm_min_ratio=1/3):
    w, v = eigen(df1, df2)
    wwr = v.min() / np.median(v)
    if wwr < eig_mm_min_ratio:
        return float('inf')
    vmin = v[:, w.argmin()]  # eigenvector with minimal eigenvalue
    nor = crossdir(df1, df2)
    return angle(vmin, nor)
```

#### A brute force approach

**Edit**: from discussion in comments, it appears that a constraint can be exploited: the two intervals have to be drawn from two larger intervals that are given.

```py
from itertools import combinations, product
from math import comb
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

def gen_intervals(df, t0, t1, t2, t3):
    """
    Given DataFrame df with DateTimeIndex, generate all
    pairs of non-overlapping time intervals with endpoints
    picked from df.index, s.t. the first is within
    [t0,t1] and the second within [t2,t3].
    """
    ix1 = df.truncate(before=t0, after=t1).index
    ix2 = df.truncate(before=t2, after=t3).index
    for (t0, t1), (t2, t3) in product(
        combinations(ix1, 2), combinations(ix2, 2)):
        yield t0, t1, t2, t3

def n_intervals(df, t0, t1, t2, t3):
    """
    Give the number of values that gen_intervals
    would generate given the same arguments.
    """
    n1 = df.truncate(before=t0, after=t1).shape[0]
    n2 = df.truncate(before=t2, after=t3).shape[0]
    return comb(n1, 2) * comb(n2, 2)

def brute(df, t0, t1, t2, t3, eig_mm_min_ratio=1/3):
    best = float('inf')
    best_ix = None
    nc = n_intervals(df, t0, t1, t2, t3)
    pb = tqdm(gen_intervals(df, t0, t1, t2, t3), total=nc)
    for ix in pb:
        df1, df2 = select(df, *ix)
        y = measure(df1, df2, eig_mm_min_ratio=eig_mm_min_ratio)
        if y < best:
            best = y
            best_ix = ix
            ixstr = [f'{t:%H:%M}' for t in ix]
            pb.set_description(f'y={y:4g} for ix={ixstr}')
    return best_ix, best
```

#### Small reproducible example

```py
n = 4  # knots
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (n, 3)),
    index=pd.date_range('2020-07-07', freq='10min', periods=n),
    columns=['r1', 'r2', 'r3']
)
df = df.resample('min').interpolate('cubic')
```

Then:

```py
# "big intervals" that should contain the small ones
interval0 = '2020-07-07 00:00:00', '2020-07-07 00:10:00'
interval1 = '2020-07-07 00:20:00', '2020-07-07 00:30:00'

# brute force exploration
ix, y = brute(df, *interval0, *interval1)

# takes ~5 sec for a df of 31 points
```

[image]

```py
>>> ix
(Timestamp('2020-07-07 00:01:00', freq='T'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-07 00:03:00', freq='T'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-07 00:23:00', freq='T'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-07 00:25:00', freq='T'))

>>> y
0.00264...
```

**Plot `df`, the two "big" intervals to chose from, and the two intervals found**:

```py
ax = df.plot()
ax.axvspan(*interval0, color='grey', alpha=0.1)
ax.axvspan(*interval1, color='grey', alpha=0.1)
ax.axvspan(ix[0], ix[1], color='grey', alpha=0.3)
ax.axvspan(ix[2], ix[3], color='grey', alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

#### Discussion

We need more information about the meaning of the measure being minimized. Not only is it very possible that drastically more efficient optimization techniques can be applied, the actual validity of the measure is called in question.

The meaning of the measure calculated is important and deserves scrutiny. Additionally, we should note conditions by which the measure can be unstable and yield unexpected results. For example, the axis of minimum variance (found by PCA) can be arbitrarily unstable: a close to spherical cloud of points (more precisely, one with close to spherical inertia) will yield a random direction that can be completely affected by as little as a single point added or removed.

Likewise, the direction orthogonal to the two barycenters can be arbitrarily unstable if the two are too close to each other.

Comment: Perhaps, I just confused and don't know how to explain. 
I'm searching for df_1 and df_2 intervals. From my data I can obviously constraint my two interval by just observing and set df_1 to be run from 09:00 to 10:00 while the df_2 to be run from 11:00 to 12:00. But within these intervals, any combinations is possible, either interval can be 1 minute or several minutes and can be anywhere within that intervals, not just running 1 minute by 1 minute as I mentioned. How to implement this

Comment: I see -- it is just a slight variation on the `select()` method above, then. E.g. you can easily code a `select_within(df, interval0, interval1)`. But the issues remain: it will still take a long time (although, less with that constraint), and fundamentally I dislike very much not understanding the **meaning** of what we are minimizing.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned there are two methods here. The minimum eigenvalue finding method is called minimum variance and the second method denoted with crossdir is called coplanar method. By using these two methods I need to find the intervals that these two methods agree the most. I actually found some interval by hand and their degree difference is only 3.5 degree, which is good, but need some algorithm or loop to weight every possibilities to find more optimized result.

Comment: I get error saying name 'product' is not defined

Comment: When I try to use the excel file for example, nothing happens it just stuck at 0/0 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

Comment: in real data, I use  seconds such as "2007-05-07 08:40:20'. Does this causes an error?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 361 entries, 0 to 360
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   epoch   361 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   r1      361 non-null    float64       
 2   r2      361 non-null    float64       
 3   r3      361 non-null    float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3)
memory usage: 11.4 KB

Comment: also get an error saying 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: I see. In the actual data, there are not only 3 vector components, but other columns too. So, how to explicitly use 3 vector components

Comment: just subset: (after setting the index, of course): when calling `brute()`, use e.g. `brute(df['r1 r2 r3'.split()], ...)`.

Comment: I keep thinking about your measure, and it still makes no sense to me. What intuition is behind this? What would two very good subsets look like, and by contrast two very bad ones? Best if you edit your answer to explain this, rather than having a conversation in comments (which is frowned upon). In my answer, I tried to provide what I understand so far, and why I think it may not be what you are looking for (read beginning and also the Discussion section).

Comment: See my edit section

Comment: Is it possible to constraint or set some if condition that the ratio between minimum and the middle eigen value should be 1/3?

Comment: Thanks but no new information there (more like a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language))).... I understand the mechanics of what you are trying to do. Heck, I even gave you a brute force way of doing exactly what you ask. What I question is the **intuition** behind it. What does it mean if the two directions ("metrics", as I call them) are close to each other angle-wise? If you take two concentrated clusters far enough from each other, you might well find a great match. Think of it geometrically and please explain the intuition.

Comment: to constrain the solution set to those where the ratio of eigenvalues (e.g. `min()/median() < 1/3`), simply return `'float('inf')` in `measure()` if the condition is violated.

Comment: For choosing eigenvectors that corresponds to the minimum eigenvalue, is
vmin = ve[va.argmin()] correct? 
Isn't the corresponding eigenvector column not row?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. I also added a minimum constraint for the ratio between min and middle eigenvalues, plus some docstrings for the interval generator.

Comment: Btw, I also made a mistake for saying to you that the minimum constraint for the ratio between minimum and middle eigenvalues should be 1/3. It should have been like equal or less than 1/3

Comment: And also if I want to include seconds, then ixstr = [f'{t:%H:%M}' for t in ix] should be written like ixstr = [f'{t:%H:%M:%S}' for t in ix] ?

Comment: That would mean that the ellipsoid of inertia, cut orthogonally to v1, has an aspect ratio of at least 1/3 -- a full circle (aspect ratio 1) would qualify. In that case (circular section perpendicular to v1), the respective orientation of v2, v3 within that section is random.

Comment: the timestamps returned are full resolution. The format used for `ixstr` is just to update the description of the progress bar. You can use whatever you'd like, it's just for info during the progress.

Comment: If my actual data has a really high resolution like 1 second in between data points and I choose 20 minutes from the first interval (df_1) and also 20 minutes for the second interval (df_2), then basically it will take forever to calculate right?

Comment: Yes. If the data is 'smooth' as I assumed it is based on your sample (that's why I generated a MRE the way I did), perhaps you can first try resampling if at a coarser resolution. Once you have found promising intervals, you can then focus on those, and also change your interval generator so that the constraints are "roughly close to `[t0,t1]`" etc.

Comment: For the confusing part, what I'm trying to find with both the method is normal vectors along x,y,z directions. So, that's why their degree difference should be as less as possible.
Btw, my implementation of covariance matrix is right, right? r1, r2, r3 are x,y,z components and they are in different columns as you can see it on data, but the data points are in rows for their corresponding columns. I'm picking up the minimum eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvectors, which should be the normal vectors that are I'm searching for.

Comment: So, corresponding eigenvectors are in column right, not in row after getting the resulting 3x3 matrix?